# Create multiplication table layout

Tags: android

I am trying to generate Multiplication Table of any number that is input by user. I have developed the interface for the application but cannot understand where to start with the logical part(coding). What i want is when a user inputs a number into the EditText then in the TextView (id: printArea) should show the table of the input number in the format as given in image 2. [Just to show you example i used TextView in the printArea part and i do not know what to use instead]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Please Enter a Number: "
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/log"
        android:onClick="submitNumber"
        android:text="Get Table" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:id="@+id/printArea" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:text="Clear" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/credits"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:text="Credits" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
            android:text="Exit" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and the MainActivity.java is:

```java
package com.example.tara.multiplicationtable;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText num;
    Button credits;
    Button calculate;
    Button clear;
    Button exit;
    TextView printArea;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        num = new EditText(this);
        clear = new Button(this);
        calculate = new Button(this);
        credits = new Button(this);
        calculate = new Button(this);
        printArea = new TextView(this);

        num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);

        credits = (Button) findViewById(R.id.credits);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        printArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printArea);


        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //change the integer value into string
                int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());

                // Perform action on click
                for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

                    printArea.setText(num1 + "X" + i + "=" + i * num1);


                }
            }
        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                num.setText("");
            }
        });
        credits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Credits.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

when application is launched it should show like this[The initial state of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFmkU.jpg)

and i want to make the application show the table like this if user input is 2  [The Final Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIeT1.jpg)

Comment: How would you do the same in regular Java? Print out the table in a for loop? You can do the exact same in Android. Just write out to the TextView instead of System.out and get your input from the EditText upon button click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the codes that i used to build the Multiplication Table that i imagined to build. The code for activity_main.xml file will be:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:text="@string/Enter_number"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/num"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:digits="0123456789"
            android:hint="@string/hidden_text"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="3"

            android:textSize="16sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/calculate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/calculate"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
    <!--android:onClick="submitNumber"-->


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/printArea"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/backimage" />

    <LinearLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/clear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/clear"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/credits"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/credits" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/exit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="@string/exit" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

The Code for the MainActivity.java file will be:

```js
package com.example.tara.multiplicationtable;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText num;
    Button credits;
    Button calculate;
    Button clear;
    Button exit;
    TextView printArea;

    //private static final String result = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        num = new EditText(this);
        clear = new Button(this);
        calculate = new Button(this);
        credits = new Button(this);
        calculate = new Button(this);
        printArea = new TextView(this);

        num = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.num);
        credits = (Button) findViewById(R.id.credits);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clear);
        exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.exit);
        calculate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.calculate);
        printArea = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.printArea);

        calculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            // Perform action on Get Table Button click
            public void onClick(View v) {


                if (num.getText().length() == 0 ){
                    printArea.setText(R.string.err_msg);
                    }

                else    {
                    //change the integer value into string
                    printArea.setText("");
                    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(num.getText().toString());
                    String result;

                    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                        result = (num1 + "      X     " + i + "      =     " + i * num1);
                        printArea.append("\n" + result);
                    }


                }
            }

        });

        clear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                num.setText("");
                printArea.setText("");
            }
        });
        credits.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Credits.class));
            }
        });



        exit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Good Bye, User!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Thank you everyone for the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Make a Listview and then in its adapter add your table data. 
Make adapter's layout like this:

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"            />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="*" />
   <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="=" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4" />
```